# Kendo chart formatting a axis

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

How do I format data being shown on a kendo ui bar chart?

I need some money values to be shown for example as "£5k" rather than "£5000".

```
        valueAxis: {
        labels: {
            format: "£{0}K"
        },
        title: {
            text: "Cover note premium"
        }
    },
```

[image]

I don't know how to divide the value being put into this graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found out how to divide a number on a label.

```
xAxis: {
   min: 8,
   max: 18,
   title: {
      text: "Hour of day"
   },
   labels: {
      template: "#= kendo.format('{0}',value/60) #"
   }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
valueAxis: {
    labels: {
        format: "£"+("{0}"/1000)+"K"
    },
    title: {
        text: "Cover note premium"
    }
```

but you should do this manipulation somewhere else, not inline.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am afraid this did not work.
I have now returned my data in a different format.

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle with your example? It would help us give a solution.

Comment: I have a had a look at jsFiddle and it looks like a good tool. I think for now I am happy with my solution of just returning different formats of data from my database. Thank you for your help

Comment: no problem. glad to help. learn to use jsfiddle, is a good way to make and share examples.